# pooled JMS connections cannot be recovered when broken

Tags: caching, connection, jms, ibm-mq, atomikos

We're using atomikos (3.9.2) to manage connection pooling and the transactions of jms  and database access. We have spring (4.1.6) beans defined as below.

```
<bean id="atomikosConnectionFactory" class="com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="xaConnectionFactory"><ref bean="jmsConnectionFactory"/></property>
        <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="ATOMIKOS_JMS_TEST"/>
        <property name="poolSize" value="5"/>
</bean>

<bean id="cachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
      <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="atomikosConnectionFactory" />
      <property name="cacheProducers" value="false" />
      <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="5" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="QUEUE.TEST" />
</bean>
```

Currently, we run into a problem when connections are broken in the connection pool, we see CachingConnectionFactory trying to reset the connections, but don't see new connections are acquired from the ibm connection factory. The application ends up hanging because of no working connections available.

Could anyone please let us know if we miss anything in the configuration or we run into some limitation of the current implementation of the used technologies.

Thanks in advance for any help or hint anyone can offer.

Comment: for some reason, the underlying connectionfactory was not posted:

Comment: <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnectionFactory">
            <property name="hostName" value="${mqdef.hostName}" />
            <property name="port" value="${mqdef.port}" />
            <property name="queueManager" value="${mqdef.queueManager}" />
            <property name="channel" value="${mqdef.channel}" />
            <property name="transportType" value="${mqdef.transportType}" />
    </bean>

Comment: When you say the connection is 'reset' do you know if it is closed and a new connection is created?  There isn't a specific reset API.  Are there any errors reported?

Comment: We saw this via spring caching connection factory log. But we don't see new mq connection is created. We know this since we have a class that is subclass of MQQueueConnectionFactory and we put some logging to track new connections.

Comment: Also there are exceptions caused by broken connection MQ reason code 2009